# Suggested edit pending but the post was already edited and approved by another person

Tags: support, bug, review, suggested-edits, askubuntu

I [suggested an edit on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1041059) at `2020-05-02 21:20:17Z`.

When I checked later, it was approved by [schrodigerscatcuriosity](https://askubuntu.com/users/931617/schrodigerscatcuriosity) at `2020-05-02 22:37:17Z` rejected by one other user. I noticed that it had already been edited by [schrodigerscatcuriosity](https://askubuntu.com/users/931617/schrodigerscatcuriosity) at `2020-05-02 21:20:16Z`, a second before my suggestion.

Now my question is **How come was I permitted to suggest an edit to a post that had already been edited?** and **Why my suggested edit showed pending as somebody else already made basically the same edit?**

Comment: This should be asked at https://meta.askubuntu.com but it is very unclear what you are asking here. The user schrodigerscatcuriosity has full edit privileges, they don't have to make a suggestion, they can just edit stuff, so it does not count as a pending edit. FYI you also seem to now have full edit privileges, so no more pending edits for you either.

Comment: @MarkKirby This question isn't specifically about the Ask Ubuntu site or policies. It's a general question about how editing works on Stack Exchange, so I don't think it needs to be sent to the other meta.

Answer (score 2):

> How come I got permitted to edit that was already been edited?

Probably a race condition or latency. Normally, when you're editing a post, you'll get a notification that somebody else has edited it and you need to reload the page. You probably just missed that notification (there only a *one second* difference between your suggested edit and the other one, and due to rounding it might be even less), and the server only checks if your edit is different (enough, i.e. 6 characters) from the current version on the server. It was (thanks to the alt text), so it processed your suggested edit, not seeing that you were doing basically the same as the first editor. It simply can't distinguish human intentions like that.

Comment: So will I rest of thinking it a one time swift computer glitch or it is a bug that might need to be fixed?

Comment: Cases like this are rare enough, and too difficult to detect programmatically, that they're generally only built in extremely vital systems (think banking; if you do two wire transfers simultaneously, they both need to be deducted from your account). It's not likely that you will encounter this again (but another person might).

Comment: But how or why did the `schrodigerscatcuriosity` approve my edit as he already did that? and can't it be block on press submit button for review as it can find duplicate on database while creating.

Comment: Perhaps they refreshed the page, saw what happened and felt pity for you? And the submit button *does* get disabled, but only if your browser gets the signal in time. This was a race condition so it didn't happen this time.